# How to list directory/file sizes in general on UNIX-like systems?

Tags: files, disk-usage, size

In general on a UNIX-like system (Linux, AIX) the following can list file/directory sizes in MByte, even if the filename is starting with a "-":

```
du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -25
```

But this doesn't list the directories/files that are "hidden", so starting with a ".". 
How can I do that in general?

This solution isn't good:

```
du -sm -- .* 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -25
```

Because it counts ".." too, and that could be slow..

Comment: The problem is du has `-a` flag but you can summerize and list all `(-a)` in the same command. So use `du -a  2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -25` and use `awk` to convert the bytes to Mbytes

Comment: For me, "-a" lists subdirectories too, that isn't needed but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
du -mad 1
```

for your purpose. Like @Miline suggested, `-a` flag will show both files and directory. Using `-d 1` will limit the output into only one layer of subdirectory(depth<=1), i.e. files of current folder and subfolder(without detail in content).